# how to live update box field in DM

Tags: dialog, dm-script

I would like a create a box with the field being update by another function (a loop in my example).
Each time value changes, the display should change.

My first attempt create a box which displays only the last value.

```
    Class MyTestDialog: UIFrame
{
    TagGroup CreateMyDialog(Object self)
    {
        TagGroup DialogTG = DLGCreateDialog("useless text")
        TagGroup Fields,FieldItems
        Fields = DLGCreateBox("Current",FieldItems)
        FieldItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateRealField(42,15,3).DLGIdentifier("#RField"))
        DialogTG.DLGAddElement(Fields.DLGTableLayOut(3,1,0))
        Return DialogTG
    }

    Void Doit(Object self,number count)
    {
        for (count=0; count<5; count++)
        {
            self.LookUpElement("#RField").DLGValue(sum(getfrontimage())*count)
            self.Display("Text at top of box window")
            sleep(3)
        }
    }
    Object Init(Object self) return self.super.Init(self.CreateMyDialog())
}
Object MyBeamCurrentDisplay = Alloc(MyTestDialog).Init()
MyBeamCurrentDisplay.Display("Text at top of box window")
sleep(3)
MyBeamCurrentDisplay.Doit(5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script actually works (except you don't want to re-display the dialog each time.), but because both the DM-script itself, as well as UI updating calls are handled on DM's main thread, you don't see an updated.

The dialog gets updated 5times, but the *display* of the dialog only gets updated once your script has finished, giving the main-thread CPU cycles to handle the UI update.

If you put your script on a background-thread, you will see it works:

```
// $BACKGROUND$
Class MyTestDialog: UIFrame
{
    TagGroup CreateMyDialog(Object self)
    {
        TagGroup DialogTG = DLGCreateDialog("useless text")
        TagGroup Fields,FieldItems
        Fields = DLGCreateBox("Current",FieldItems)
        FieldItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateRealField(42,15,3).DLGIdentifier("#RField"))
        DialogTG.DLGAddElement(Fields.DLGTableLayOut(3,1,0))
        Return DialogTG
    }

    Void Doit(Object self,number count)
    {
        for (count=0; count<5; count++)
        {
            self.LookUpElement("#RField").DLGValue(sum(getfrontimage())*count)
            // self.Display("Text at top of box window")
            sleep(0.1)
        }
    }
    Object Init(Object self) return self.super.Init(self.CreateMyDialog())
}
Object MyBeamCurrentDisplay = Alloc(MyTestDialog).Init()
MyBeamCurrentDisplay.Display("Text at top of box window")
sleep(0.2)
MyBeamCurrentDisplay.Doit(20)
```

(The first line of the code has to be *exactly* `// $BACKGROUND` )

An alternative way is to keep the script on the main thread, but add `doEvents()` before your `sleep(0.1)` to give some CPU cycles to the main application finishing queued task like updating UI's.

---

I also played a bit with updates and different threads and thought you might find the following example useful:

```c
number TRUE = 1
number FALSE = 0

Class MyTestDialog: UIFrame
{
    object messageQueue
    object stoppedSignal
    number updateTimeSec

    void OnUpdateStateChanged(object self, taggroup checkboxTG )
    {
        if ( TRUE == checkboxTG.DLGGetValue() )
            self.StartThread( "RegularFrontImageUpdate" )
        else 
            messageQueue.PostMessage( Alloc(object) )   // Single message: Stop, so any object will do
    }
    
    number AboutToCloseDocument( object self, number verify )
    {
        result("\nAbout to close")
        messageQueue.PostMessage( Alloc(object) )   // Single message: Stop, so any object will do
        stoppedSignal.WaitOnSignal( infinity(), NULL )  // Ensure we don't kill the UI object while the update thread is still accessing it
        return FALSE
    }

    TagGroup CreateMyDialog(Object self)
    {
        TagGroup DialogTG = DLGCreateDialog("useless text")
        TagGroup Fields,FieldItems
        Fields = DLGCreateBox("Current Front Image Sum",FieldItems)
        FieldItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateStringField("No front image",30).DLGIdentifier("#StrField").DLGEnabled(FALSE))
        FieldItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateRealField(0,15,3).DLGIdentifier("#RField").DLGEnabled(FALSE))
        FieldItems.DLGAddElement(DLGCreateCheckbox("Update", TRUE, "OnUpdateStateChanged").DLGIdentifier("#ToggleCheck"))
        DialogTG.DLGAddElement(Fields.DLGTableLayOut(3,1,0))
        Return DialogTG
    }

    void RegularFrontImageUpdate(Object self)
    {
        stoppedSignal.ResetSignal()
        self.SetElementIsEnabled("#RField",TRUE)
        self.SetElementIsEnabled("#StrField",TRUE)
        result("\nEnabling auto-update")    
        while(TRUE)
        {
            object message = messageQueue.WaitOnMessage( updateTimeSec, null )
            if ( message.ScriptObjectIsValid() )
            {
                // Handle message. We just use 'empty' objects in this example
                //  as we only have a "single" message: Stop updating now!
                self.LookUpElement("#ToggleCheck").DLGValue( 0 )                    
                self.LookUpElement("#RField").DLGValue( 0 )
                self.SetElementIsEnabled("#RField",FALSE)
                self.SetElementIsEnabled("#StrField",FALSE)
                result("\nDisabling auto-update")   
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                // Timeout of waiting time. Just update             
                image front := FindFrontImage()
                
                if ( front.ImageIsValid() )
                {
                    self.LookUpElement("#RField").DLGValue( sum(front) )
                    self.LookUpElement("#StrField").DLGValue( front.GetName() )
                }
                else
                    self.LookUpElement("#ToggleCheck").DLGValue( 0 )
            }       
        }     
        stoppedSignal.SetSignal()   
    }
    object Launch(object self)
    {
        updateTimeSec = 0.1
        messageQueue = NewMessageQueue()
        stoppedSignal = NewSignal( false )
        self.Init(self.CreateMyDialog()).Display("Title")
        self.StartThread( "RegularFrontImageUpdate" )       
        return self
    }    
}
Alloc(MyTestDialog).Launch()
```

Comment: @NMJB You're welcome. See also updated answer with additional example on  how I would handle auto-updates on a separate thread.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It seems more complicated to fully grasp...

Comment: @NMJB It is, but it also shows the use of two other concepts (message queues and signals) which are important when working with multiple threads. BTW, I just amended my answer *again* as I forgot about an alternative, the command 'DoEvents()' which a script on the main-thread can use to give a bit of CPU cycles to other tasks of the application.